# Document Sets and Client Object Model

Tags: document-library, client-object-model

What are the options to manage documents sets using Client Object Model?
I need to create new document sets and upload some files in them...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a good blog post on using document sets with the client OM:
[Document Sets and Client Object Model](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-your-sharepoint-2010.html)